# How to parse li and ul tags in android into a listview using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

[image][image]Hi there…am having problems parsing the following HTML code using Jsoup. I cant even figure out which tag to parse in this situation. Please help. Am new to android and know how to parse individual tags like h3 and h2 but am stuck on how to parse these individual "li" tags and display them in a list view. Cheers
[image: Android Java Code]

[image]

Comment: You should add codes, instead of taking screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the `<li>` tags of every `<ul>` tags by:

```
Elements listTags = doc.select("ul li");
```

**An example:**

```
Elements listTags = doc.select("ul li");
Elements headingItems = doc.select("h3");

List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element item : listTags) {
    items.add(item.text());
}

List<String> headings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element item : headingItems) {
    headings.add(item.text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks have tried this and only get a single li and not all of them in which i am trying to store into an array of strings. Here is my code posted above. Not sure if I'm even on the right track =(

Comment: @Charlie Please post this code on your question instead of in the comments. It's very hard to read.

Comment: sorry just did as i saw it was difficult to read. Have posted it up in the question area. Thanks

Comment: nope sorry.. I'm trying to take each of those individual li tags and store it into a Array of strings and then call the get method on that array to assign it to individual strings in which i can display on a textview.

Comment: @Charlie well I just tried it myself and it seems that `"ul li"` , as I originally suggested, works. Furthermore I noticed a comma in the code you posted, that may be causing your problems. Try removing that.

Comment: have tried but still no change. Could it be in my onPostExecuteMethod? Have posted the code..

Comment: @Charlie Okay well I noticed more mistakes in your code. You are creating new arrays for every Element that you loop. I updated my code with a decent example.

Comment: it works… your awesome.. thanks! one more question if you can please. How can i extract out only this portion of the HTML li/ul tags if there are a tone of other li/ul tags in the HTML document.. Is there a way to call a certain tag from this portion of code to tell my program that i am only referring to the following "li" tags in this portion of code?

Comment: @Charlie You have to somehow distinguish between the ul's that you need and the  ones you don't. Possible ways are parent tags, some ul attribute or the index. You should read more about the [syntax of jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). If you have further questions, you better ask another one in SO :)